# Wrong bounding rect for right aligned text in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectForGlyphRange:(NSRange)glyphRange inTextContainer:(NSTextContainer *)container;
```

returns wrong rect for glyph range when attributed text is right aligned in UILabel. How to fix this please ?

Code to calculate the bounding rect of attributed text when tapped on UILabel (textAlignment set to right in UILabel)

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
    CGSize labelSize = recognizer.view.bounds.size;

    NSTextContainer *container = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:labelSize];
    container.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
    container.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode;
    container.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines;

    NSLayoutManager *manager = [NSLayoutManager new];
    [manager addTextContainer:container];

    NSTextStorage *storage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
    [storage addLayoutManager:manager];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:label];
    NSInteger indexOfCharacter = [manager characterIndexForPoint:touchPoint
                                                 inTextContainer:container
                        fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(indexOfCharacter, 1);
    NSRange glyphRange;
    [manager characterRangeForGlyphRange:range actualGlyphRange:&glyphRange];
    CGRect rect = [manager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange inTextContainer:container];
}
```

Comment: UILabel gives you no access to the text kit stack, so where is that call even coming from? Show actual code with actual context if you want actual help. Thanks!

Comment: @matt Added the code

Comment: How did you make your label right-aligned? If by setting its alignment, that's the problem. The `label.attributedText` wouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: @matt Thanks Man !! Set the alignment using paragraph Style and it all worked fine

Comment: Oh! Well, I'll give that as an answer, hold on a sec.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are setting the label's `text` and `textAlignment`, and then pulling out the label's `attributedText` and handing it to the text kit stack, in the belief that it magically translates your label configuration into an attributed string. It doesn't!

If you want right-aligned text that the text kit stack can see as right-aligned, set your label's `attributedText` *only*, endowing it with features such as a right-aligned paragraph style.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this!!

The problem was the label was made to be right aligned using `textAlignment` property of UILabel. As mentioned in comments `label.attributedText` doesn't know anything about it.

Instead add text alignment using `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` as :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = [NSMutableAttributedString new];
//Add to your string
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
[mutableString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableString.length)];
label.attributedText = mutableString;
```